# Is it possible to require a login for an OpenCart Information page, and ONLY the information page?

Tags: php, opencart

I see many extensions that make you log in before viewing the products and such, but I only want to restrict access to a certain page that I created by creating a new information page. Is this possible? I am also not very proficient with php so please tell me which files I should be editing and where. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should accept the answer below. Use the tick on the left to the answer. Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding this at the top of **controller/information/information.php** straight after the **index()** function declaration and replace {ID} with the ID of the page you want to password protect (you can get the ID from the URL, or if you have SEO URLs, from the admin section).

```
if (isset($this->request->get['information_id']) && $this->request->get['information_id'] == '{ID}') {
    //If the information_id is provided and it matches the ID you wish to protect
    if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
        //If the customer is not logged in already, redirect them to the login page
        //Use $this->session->data['redirect'] to redirect them back to this page after logging in
        $this->session->data['redirect'] = $this->url->link('information/information', 'information_id=' . $this->request->get['information_id']);
        //Do the redirect
        $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
    }
}
```

I've assumed that the information page **is not** using SSL in the above example, you'll need to modify it if it is.

If you're getting confused as to where this should go, have a look at **controller/account/account.php** - i've taken this code from there and modified it for a specific information page.

Comment: @user1835998 If You would like to restrict more than one information page, change the first condition (first line) to this: `if (isset($this->request->get['information_id']) && in_array($this->request->get['information_id'], array(ID1, ID2, ID3))) {`.

Comment: Yes, `in_array` is better if you intend to password protect more than 1 page.