# Display information page to only logged in and particular customer group

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, opencart, restrict

I found this following code on stackoverflow which gives access to information page to only logged in customer, and it is very useful. I want one enhancement to this. The information page should be only accessible by particular customer group.

```
if (isset($this->request->get['information_id']) && $this->request->get['information_id'] == '{ID}') 
{
    //If the information_id is provided and it matches the ID you wish to protect
    if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
        //If the customer is not logged in already, redirect them to the login page
        //Use $this->session->data['redirect'] to redirect them back to this page after logging in
        $this->session->data['redirect'] = $this->url->link('information/information', 'information_id=' . $this->request->get['information_id']);
        //Do the redirect
        $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
    }
}
```

Code Source: [Is it possible to require a login for an OpenCart Information page, and ONLY the information page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455386/is-it-possible-to-require-a-login-for-an-opencart-information-page-and-only-the)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your second `if` condition as shown below:

```
if (isset($this->request->get['information_id']) && $this->request->get['information_id'] == '{ID}') {

    if (!$this->customer->isLogged() || $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId()  != 1) { //where '1' is your customer groupid for which you want to give access.. 

        $this->session->data['redirect'] = $this->url->link('information/information', 'information_id=' . $this->request->get['information_id']);
        $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
    }
}
```

`$this->customer->getCustomerGroupId()` - returns your customer group id.

Have a nice day :) !!

Comment: Something going wrong. Redirection is ok but showing to all customer group. Help!!!

Comment: if (!$this->customer->isLogged() `||` $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId()  != 1) { - updated.. please find my updated answer. earlier i used `AND` instead of `OR`.